# Enviar Modal con Ajax a php

Tags: php, ajax, modal

Tengo un modal donde recibo información desde una consulta sql, quiero modificar un campo y actualizar esa información en la base de datos enviando esa misma información mediante ajax a php para realizar el update, pero no logro hacer, no recibo el echo desde php y pasa a la funcion fail.... y no se donde ver el error que causa o por que falla...

Tambien como podria depurar mi codigo para ver el comportamiento del script?

GRACIAS...!!

Este es mi modal.....

```
<div class="modal fade" id="veregistro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" action="actuAva.php">
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
        <form id="actua"  role="form">
        <div class="modal-content" id="contenido">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver informe / Editar</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">ID:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="ida" readonly="readonly" name="ida">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Carpeta:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="carpeta" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Num. intervenidos:</span>
                    <textarea type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="intervenidos" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Juez:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="juez" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Num. de resolucion:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="resolucion" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Fecha de Inicio:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="finicio" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Fecha de termino:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="ftermino" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Informe inicial:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="inicial" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Mes 1:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="mes1" readonly="readonly">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Mes 2:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="mes2" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Mes 3:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="mes3" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Terminacion:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="terminacion" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Conclusion A.:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="conclusion" readonly="readonly" >
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Objetivos:</span>
                    <textarea type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="objetivos" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Avances:</span>
                    <textarea type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" id="avances"  name="avances"></textarea>
                </div>  
            </div>
            </div>                  
                <div class="modal-footer" id="footer-2">  
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar / Cerrar</button>                           
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#"  type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Actualizar</a> 
                </div>                       
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el scrip. Aquí donde imprimo la variable actualizar recibe correctamente la información, pero no se ejecuta la funcion done...

```
 $(function(){
       $('body').on('click', '#footer-2 a', function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var actualizar = $('#avances').val();
           var ida = $('#ida').val();
           console.log(actualizar+" "+ida);
           $.ajax({
                 url: 'actuAva.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: 'action=upFuncion&id_lista='+ida+'&avances='+actualizar,
                 cache: false
           }).done(function(response){
               console.log("aqui estoy");
               alert(response.mensaje);
           }).fail(function(resp){
               console.log("error no termino correctamente..");
           }).always(function(resp){
               console.log("complete SEGUNDO");
           })                                      
       });
   });
```

Codigo PHP para realizar la operacion de actualizacion de datos en la base de datos.....

```
$ID =$_POST['ida2'];
$AVA = $_POST['avances2'];


//conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.13", "XXX", "XXXXX", "BD");
$consulta = "UPDATE intervenciones SET avances='$AVA' Where 
idintervenciones='$ID'";

if(mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){

   echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Record updated  Successfully"); 
   window.location.href="home.php"</script>';  
}
else{
  echo "error al guardar registro verifique sus datos";
  echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error".$consulta." 
  <br>".mysqli_error($conexion)); window.location.href="home.php"</script>';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Hola, en base a tu código, ¿te gustaría te proponga una versión un poco más optimizada para enviar y recibir los datos como los necesitas?

Comment: @FernandoUrban Hola.. Mira lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente espero se me entienda:

Tengo un modal que me muestra información detallada de un registro de una base de datos, en este modal todos los campos no son edita bles, excepto el ultimo, este al modificarle algo quiero que al darle actualizar envie ese nuevo dato con ajax a php para hacer la consulta en sql..

Comment: Vale, por favor explícame un poco mejor, gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Te diría que cambies lo siguiente:

En tu llamada Ajax:

```
$(function(){
       $('body').on('click', '#footer-2 a', function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var actualizar = $('#avances').val(), // si declaras varias variables separalas con coma
           ida = $('#ida').val();
           console.log(actualizar+" "+ida);
           $.ajax({
                 url: 'actuAva.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {action : "upFuncion", id_lista : ida, avances : actualizar},//envia un arreglo de datos post 
                 cache: false
           }).done((res)=>{
               //puedes enviar el mensaje y la respuesta desde el back end 
               if(res.respuesta != undefined && res.respuesta == 'ok'){
                 alert(res.msg);
                 window.location.href="home.php"
              }else{
                alert(resp.msg);
                window.location.href="home.php"
              }
           }).fail((resp)=>{
               console.log("error no termino correctamente..");
           }).always((resp)=>{
               console.log("complete SEGUNDO");
           })                                      
       });
   });
```

en php:

```
$ID = (isset($_POST['id_lista']) ? $_POST['id_lista'] : '');// aqui es id_lista no ida2
$AVA = (isset($_POST['avances']) ? $_POST['avances'] : ''); //aqui es avances no avances2


//conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.13", "XXX", "XXXXX", "BD");
```

En tu consulta deberias utilizar prepared statements para evitar inyección de sql puedes guiarte en este [articulo](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

```
$consulta = "UPDATE intervenciones SET avances='$AVA' Where 
idintervenciones='$ID'"; // en tu query normalmente una id es numerica no si aqui deberia ser idintervenciones = $ID

if(mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){
   //aquí solo regresa la respuesta y el mensaje del alert no un script
   echo  json_encode(['respuesta'=>'ok', 'msg'=>'Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente']);
}
else{
  //lo mismo aquí
  echo  json_encode(['respuesta'=>'ok', 'msg'=>'error al guardar registro verifique sus datos']);
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Saludos